# onHandelIntent() function in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

This is a small snippet from http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
which describes services in android.

```
public class HelloIntentService extends IntentService {

  /**
   * A constructor is required, and must call the super IntentService(String)
   * constructor with a name for the worker thread.
   */
  public HelloIntentService() {
      super("HelloIntentService");
  }

  /**
   * The IntentService calls this method from the default worker thread with
   * the intent that started the service. When this method returns, IntentService
   * stops the service, as appropriate.
   */
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
      // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
      long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5*1000;
      while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
          synchronized (this) {
              try {
                  wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
              } catch (Exception e) {
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Concept:
onStartservices() handles the thread synchronization itself as mentioned
and synchronized is used to handle synchronization

Question.
why is synchronization(this) explicitly defined even though onstartservices() takes care of it?

Comment: what do you mean onstartservices() take care of it? Would you please also share that code.?

Comment: onstartService() handles the multi threading part. I was talking about that. But I am still not getting the solution.But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we call startService(),there will be only one service created at a given time.

So ,if the `Service` instance already exists , it will be reused, if there are some property defined in your Service and If you are trying to use them from both the worker thread(onHandleIntent is called in worker thread) and the main thread(`onCreate`, `onStartCommand` etc are called in main thread), you will need to synchronize the Service instance.

you may log in `onCreate()` to see if two intents is handled in the same `IntentService` instance.

> The system calls this method when the service is first created, to
>   perform one-time setup procedures (before it calls either
>   onStartCommand() or onBind()). If the service is already running, this
>   method is not called.

Answer (score 1):

`synchronised` block is used only because of the `wait()` method. Without it, wait() method would be called over and over again until estimated time expiry. With `synchronised` block `wait()` method is executed once(assuming it's not interrupted)

Normally you would implement only your application logic there.

On the same site you linked, above the sample code, there is a crucial sentence:

> Creates a work queue that passes one intent at a time to your
>   onHandleIntent() implementation, so you never have to worry about
>   multi-threading.